# JavaScript Objects and Scope

Tags: javascript

I have some JavaScript that looks like this:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    // Constructor function for our ContentView class
    var OtherObject = require('OtherObject');

    function MyObject() {
        this.currentThing = null;

        setThing();
        var b = new OtherObject(moving);
    }

    function setThing() {
        this.currentThing = "A string!";
    }

    function moving() {
        console.log(this.currentThing);        
    }

    module.exports = MyObject;
});
```

And an object in another file that looks like this:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    // Constructor function for our ContentView class
    function OtherObject(callback) {
        this.whatever = null;

        callback();
    }

    module.exports = OtherObject;
});
```

I want to let the OtherObject use a callback when something happens internally, and have that callback access an object instantiated in the MyObject file. However, whenever moving() is called, this.currentThing is undefined. I'm probably overlooking something obvious here, but I'd love some help!

Comment: `this` in `setThing()` and `moving()` is not a `MyObject`, it's `window`. Those functions are defined outside of the scope of `MyObject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the value of `this` when `callback` is called and its value is the `moving` function is not the `MyObject` instance.

I could tell you how to fix your problem, but that would hardly teach you much. Instead, read [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md) and then [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md), no pun intended.